# Настроить докер с PASS OpenPGP secret key

Tags: linux, docker, devops

Создал pipeline в azure devops. На сервере настроил докер, чтобы получить образ мне необходимо авторизоваться. Далее, за счет того, что пароль в докер при авторизации храниться просто в незащищенном виде, настроил standard unix password manager(PASS). Но тут и встрял, чтобы вся автоматизация взлетела, надо пароль ввести после `pass docker-credential-helpers/docker-pass-initialized-check`, но далее получаю вот такое окно [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И как я туда должен вставить пароль?

Может есть какой выход, ума пока что не приложу

Comment: Ну в https://www.passwordstore.org/ пишут про `~/.password-store`. Может туда положить?

Comment: Там у меня и храниться все. Чтобы туда попасть надо ввести пароль как и в любом pass manager

Comment: Оно? https://gist.github.com/layoaster/473b38104611662ad74f1045842403d3#insert

Comment: Не, это не то снова. У меня там есть уже пароль, все отлично. Но доступ к нему разрешен после введения как такового мастер пароля. Мне необходимо разблокировать хранилище автоматически при деплое моего проекта, через скрипт, автоматически вставить пароль. По ssh вручную это без проблем сделать, а вот в то окно что выше я прикрепил, вставить мастер пароль для разблокировки через скрипт не получается

Comment: Ну как быдлохак - попробуй `expect`.